# Putting like terms together using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

The following code puts together the like terms. However with large number of terms it might get lot more difficult to add up all the like terms. Any suggestion on how this can be accomplished without the tedious approach I am currently employing.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import *
x,y,a,b,c,d=sp.symbols('x,y,a,b,c,d')
A=a*x + b*y
B=c*x+d*y
A1=A.coeff(x)
B1=B.coeff(x)                    #segregating the coefficients
A2=A.coeff(y)
B2=B.coeff(y)
A_new=(A1+B1)*x + (A2+B2)*y
print A_new
```

The output is

```
x*(a + c) + y*(b + d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sympy as sp

x,y,a,b,c,d=sp.symbols('x,y,a,b,c,d')
A = a*x + b*y
B = c*x+d*y
sum_expr = A+B
sum_expr.collect((x,y))  # output: x*(a + c) + y*(b + d)
```

It's written in [the tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#collect) too.